# How many Arks were built in the film 2012?

Tags: 2012

I was watching 2012 the other night on DVD & started thinking about how many Arks that  were built (going to be built) in the film. From what I can remember, when they start to have problems near the start of the film, there was something about 4 being completed but one got damaged. But someone told me that there was a scene where someone on one of the Arks contacts the other Arks & on the communication console there were **nine** graphics/ buttons for the Arks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the script, there were bays for nine arks. When the crisis began earlier than expected, four of the nine were ready to launch. Ark #4 was damaged when the roof of its bay collapsed, so only three actually launched.

Here's the discussion between Anheuser and the President discussing the readiness of the Arks:

> **ANHEUSER:** Sir, you have to initiate the boarding process immediately.
>
> **PRESIDENT WILSON:** Is this even possible? What's our information from China?
>
> **ANHEUSER:** They estimate four of the ships will be ready for launch.
>
> **PRESIDENT WILSON:** (The President is shocked by this news.) Only four?

Then, later, when we actually see the Arks:

> **EXT. CHO MING VALLEY/TIBET - DAWN**
>
> The CAMERA follows the choppers revealing nine gigantic oval gates that measure at least 60 stories, built into the face of a mountain.
>
> In front of every gate there is a line of huge `Y' shaped metal support structures, which are the launching towers for the ships. They are each at least 800 feet high. It's an unparalleled feat of engineering.

So, looks like you're both correct.